Number field formatted as percentage, displays as a ratio when attempting to edit its value
I have a ratio numeric field which is editable and it is set to have percentage formatting using the column attribute:
{
   field: weight,
   editable: true,
   valueFormatter: percentFormatter,
   valueParser: 'Number(newValue)'    
}

However, when the user clicks the cell to edit it, she sees a ratio instead of a percentage. How to make sure that the users always sees a percentage though the field is internally stored a ratio? Is there a dedicated AG Grid configuration for that?

format the number before handing it over to AG Grid and convert it back before sending it to your backend. Or implement a custom cell editor and attach the field to it

could you provide some example data/screenshots/plunker?
